# Как отключить обновления Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

1. Как отключить автоматическое обновление Windows 10 (если возможно полное отключение обновлений)?
2. Как отключить автоматическое обновление драйверов Windows 10?

P.S. Простое отключение службы обновлений ничего не дает.

Comment: Но если не Home, то вместо выдергивания шнура можно перейти на использование windows update minitool. А также зайти в дополнительные параметры в разделе обновления в панели управления вин и выставить отложенное обновление компонентов на 365 дней

Comment: А есть ещё какие-то решения?

Comment: Посмотрите этот твикер, не помню есть там про обновления, но там много чего: https://jailbreakvideo.ru/win-10-tweaker

Comment: У меня лет 6 назад были проблемы с обновлениями винды - они не хотели устанавливаться. Из за этого я перешёл на линукс и с тех пор винду в глаза не видел. Так вот, реально фигею с вашего вопроса - вы спрашиваете как намерено превратить систему в глючную помойку!? Лично я обновляюсь каждый день, причём предпочитаю делать это вручную, потому что банально интересно, что там новенького! Странные вы, виндоюзеры...

Answer (score 0):

1.Откройте приложение «Параметры» и перейдите в раздел Обновление и безопасность -> Центр обновления Windows.

2.Нажмите на кнопку «Параметры перезапуска».

3. Сначала выберите «Получать больше уведомлений». Так вы запретите Windows автоматически перезагружать компьютер после скачивания и установки обновлений.

4.Вернитесь на предыдущий экран и выберите пункт "Дополнительные параметры".

5.Теперь выключите опцию «При обновлении Windows предоставить обновления для других продуктов Майкрософт».

6.Теперь активируйте параметр «Отложить обновления». Когда эта опция включена, новые обновления не будут загружаться и устанавливаться в течение нескольких дней или месяцев, за исключением обновлений для системы безопасности.

7.Наконец, нажмите на ссылку «Выберите, как и когда получать обновления» и переведите переключатель «Обновление из нескольких мест» в состояние «Откл». Это поможет в экономии интернет-трафика, так как эта функция работает по принципу технологии P2P или торрент-клиентов

Драйвера:
Новая система все еще позволяет предотвратить автоматическую загрузку и установку драйверов. Вот как это сделать:

Откройте диалог «Выполнить» с помощью сочетания клавиш win + R.
Введите команду rundll32 newdev.dll,DeviceInternetSettingUi и нажмите Enter, чтобы открыть окно «Параметры установки устройств».

В открывшемся окне сначала выберите «Нет, предоставить возможность выбора», а затем «Никогда не устанавливать драйверы из Центра обновления Windows».

Сохраните изменения.
После этого Windows всегда будет искать и устанавливать драйверы с компьютера, а к Центру обновления система будет обращаться только в случае, если подходящий драйвер не будет найден на жестком диске.

Первая ссылка гугла :/

Comment: ну дак, обновления безопасности и критические обновы все равно будут устаналиваться

Answer (score 0):

1) Отключите службу обновления Windows.

2) Удалите все наследуемые разрешения и установите ЗАПРЕТ для "Все" на папку

```
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore
```

(в Свойства папки -> вкладка Безопасность)

Перезагрузите комп.

Мне помогло.